# Translate Ajax.Request (prototype.js library) to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Using the prototype.js library:

```
function submit_the_form(event, url) {
  var options: {method: 'put'};
  new Ajax.Request(url + '?' + $(event).form.serialize(), options);
}
```

My attempt at translating this to jQuery:

```
function submit_the_form(event, url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    data: $(event).serialize()
  });
}
```

This throws the error "too many redirects", and I see it making lots and lots of database calls in my terminal.

Any ideas how I might have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When is the function `submit_the_form()` called? Is it triggered when a button is clicked, (default) form submission, etc.?